# How much energy is needed to curve the space so the Sun will come 1 meter closer to our planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spacetime, space, sun, earth

How much energy/work will it take if our planet is:

```
5.9736×1024 kg
```

or

```
3.0×10−6 Suns
```

to move Sun and Earth 1 meter closer to each other?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate it easily first calculate the gravitational potential energy between earth and sun in their initial state and then calculate it when they are 1 meter closer and find the difference. That's the value you want 
                              $U$ = $\frac{GM1M2}{R}$
where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant $M1$
 and $M2$ are the masses of the two bodies and $R$ is the distance between the two bodies.
But i want to tell you that this will be not the accurate value as I have neglected the effect dude to another planets on the system. If you want to calculate the accurate figure's you need to find out the initial and final potential of the whole solar system.